# Is there any difference with or without и on "тот же ~, как..." structure?

Tags: грамматика, разница

In the following sentence:

> У неё такая же кофточка, как у тебя.

I thought that usually, these types of sentences also use и, such as:

> У неё такая же кофточка, как и у тебя.

I wonder if there is any difference between the two sentences. Are they exactly the same, or is there any difference, even slightly, between the two?

Comment: There's no actually any difference, maybe the one with _и_ is a bit more colloquial, although the difference is perhaps so minute that it can hardly be noticed.

Comment: @YellowSky Could you write it in an answer?

Comment: In a one-sentence answer containing the words ‘maybe’, ‘perhaps’, and ‘hardly’ at the same time? What I wrote is just what I _feel_ as a native speaker, but I would rather write what I _know_ in my answers. I'm sure there are people here who _know_, it's just the end-summer trance now, soon they'll be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two constructions are almost identical in meaning, but the one with "и" has a slight connotation of the statement being anticipated. For example:

```
— Как склоняется слово «такой»?
— Это слово склоняется так же, как прилагательные.
```

*(new information)*

or:

```
— Как склоняется слово «такой»?
— Это местоимение-прилагательное; склоняется оно так же, как и прилагательные.
```

*(expected conclusion)*

Similarly, compare:

```
— Вот это совпадение, посмотри! У неё такая же кофточка, как у тебя.
```

```
— Не выдумывай, вы обе хорошо выглядите! У неё такая же кофточка, как и у тебя.
```

But this nuance in meaning is very minor indeed, so in practice you would almost always be using the two constructions interchangeably.